# trying to add to bag and to update prices and cups

Tags: flutter

I am trying to do this test TODOs: but i have been have issuses pls help: i am trying to Uncomment the _confirmOrderModalBottomSheet() method to show summary of order, Uncomment the setState() function to clear the price and cups, and Change the 'price' to 0 when this button is clicked Increment the _cupsCounter when 'Add to Bag' button is clicked, and to Call setState((){}) method to update both price and cups counter when 'Add to Bag' button is clicked

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Coffee Test',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Coffee Test'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  int _selectedPosition = -1;

  String _coffeePrice ="0";

  int _cupsCounter =0;

  int price = 0;

  String _currency ="₦";

  static const String coffeeCup ="images/coffee_cup_size.png";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          title: FlatButton(
              onPressed: (){
                //TODO: Uncomment the _confirmOrderModalBottomSheet() method to show summary of order
                //_confirmOrderModalBottomSheet(totalPrice: "$_currency$price", numOfCups: "x $_cupsCounter");
              },
              child: Text("Buy Now",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87),),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0), side: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue))
          ),
          actions: [
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                //TODO: Uncomment the setState() function to clear the price and cups
                //TODO: Change the 'price' to 0 when this button is clicked
                setState(() {
                  this.price = -1;
                  this._cupsCounter = 0;
                });

                Icon(Icons.clear);
              }),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Container(
                height: double.maxFinite,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text("$_cupsCounter Cups = $_currency$price.00", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20), child: _mainBody(),) // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }


  Widget _mainBody(){
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        height: double.maxFinite,
        width: double.maxFinite,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
                flex: 0,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: double.maxFinite,
                      height: 250,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, top: 60),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(180)),
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(239, 235, 233, 100)),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      width: double.maxFinite,
                      height: 350,
                      child: Image.asset("images/cup_of_coffee.png", height: 300,),
                    )
                  ],
                )),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),),
            Expanded(flex: 0,child: Text("Caffè Americano",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 30),)),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),),
            Expanded(flex: 0, child: Text("Select the cup size you want and we will deliver it to you in less than 48hours",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black45,),
              textAlign: TextAlign.start,),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, left: 20),
              height: 55,
              width: double.maxFinite,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child:Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  RichText(text: TextSpan(
                      text: _currency,
                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 25, color: Colors.black87),
                      children: [
                        TextSpan(text: _coffeePrice, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                      ]
                  ),),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                  ),
                  ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index){

                    return InkWell(
                      child: _coffeeSizeButton(_selectedPosition == index,
                          index ==0? "S" : index ==1? "M": "L"),
                      onTap: (){
                        setState(() {
                          this._coffeePrice= index ==0? "300" : index ==1? "600": "900";
                          _selectedPosition = index;
                        });
                      },
                    );
                  }, scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: 3, shrinkWrap: true,),

                ],),
            ),

            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              width: double.maxFinite,
              height: 70,
              child: FlatButton(onPressed: (){
                //TODO: Currently _cupsCounter only show 1 when this button is clicked.
                // TODO: Increment the _cupsCounter when 'Add to Bag' button is clicked'
                //TODO: Call setState((){}) method to update both price and cups counter when 'Add to Bag' button is clicked

                this._cupsCounter = 1;
                this.price += int.parse(_coffeePrice);
              }, child: Center(child: Text("Add to Bag",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),)
                ,),
                color: Colors.blue,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _coffeeSizeButton(bool isSelected, String coffeeSize){
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(alignment: Alignment.center,  width: 55,
          child: Text(coffeeSize, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: isSelected? Colors.blue: Colors.black45),),),
        new Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
          child: Image.asset(coffeeCup, width:50, color: isSelected ? Colors.blue: Colors.black45,),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border(top: BorderSide(color: isSelected? Colors.blue: Colors.black45,
              width: isSelected? 2: 1), left: BorderSide(color: isSelected? Colors.blue: Colors.black45,
              width: isSelected? 2: 1), bottom: BorderSide(color: isSelected? Colors.blue: Colors.black45,
              width: isSelected? 2: 1), right:  BorderSide(color: isSelected ?Colors.blue: Colors.black45 ,
              width: isSelected? 2: 1)), borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  void _confirmOrderModalBottomSheet({String totalPrice, String numOfCups}){
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (builder){
          return new Container(
            height: 150.0,
            color: Colors.transparent, //could change this to Color(0xFF737373),
            //so you don't have to change MaterialApp canvasColor
            child: new Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: const Radius.circular(10.0),
                        topRight: const Radius.circular(10.0))),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Text("Confirm Order",
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),),
                      alignment: Alignment.center, height: 30, decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    ), ),
                    _getEstimate(totalPrice, numOfCups)
                  ],
                )),
          );
        }
    );
  }

  Widget _getEstimate(String totalPrice, String numOfCups){
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: [
        Image.asset("images/cup_of_coffee.png", height: 70, width: 50,),
        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
        Text(numOfCups, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
        Text(totalPrice, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
      ],
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting 1 to your `_cupsCounter` instead of adding one to it.

When updating your values, putting the operation i.e `_cupsCounter += 1;` in setState will update the state of your widget which makes values change in your widgets.

```dart
setState((){
   _cupsCounter += 1; // make it +=1 instead of =1.
   price += int.parse(_coffeePrice);
});
```

Also you can use setState by putting it after your operation which will update the state of your widget after the operation is done.

```dart
_cupsCounter += 1; // make it +=1 instead of =1.
price += int.parse(_coffeePrice);
setState((){});
```

Full code should look like this.

```dart
Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        width: double.maxFinite,
        height: 70,
        child: FlatButton(onPressed: (){
          // Currently _cupsCounter only show 1 when this button is clicked.
          //  Increment the _cupsCounter when 'Add to Bag' button is clicked'
          // Call setState((){}) method to update both price and cups counter when 'Add to Bag' button is clicked
          setState((){
             _cupsCounter += 1; // make it +=1 instead of =1.
             price += int.parse(_coffeePrice);
          }); // call setState like this
        }, child: Center(child: Text("Add to Bag",
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),)
          ,),
          color: Colors.blue,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)
          ),
        ),
      )
```

Comment: The setState is there, take a look at the code again. maybe refresh this page

Comment: so pls man can u explain to me how you came abt it so i can know it pls

Comment: I added some explanations, i hope it helps you

Comment: pls man i dont know if u can help me out i add the full code and i have some error in them can u pls help do the TODOs?

Comment: i have dont the one you did for me but there are some other TODOs i am have issuses with i need your help